# How to stop a video from a web page from continuing to play after I shut down web page?

Tags: video, samsung-galaxy-s7

I often play videos that are embedded in a web page.

When I close Google or Chrome, the video keeps playing and I can't find it.

What setting do I need to change so that the video stops when I close the web page?

Comment: I think this is simply a bug of latest Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Go to setting /system. You can turn off Running background app when Google chrome is closed. When web page is closed, it will not play video.

You can reset setting to default.
[image]